# insert into <x> select * from <y> results in error: Invalid object name '<y>'

Tags: sql-server

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct
>   28 2016 18:17:30      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Express
>   Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3  (Build 15063: )
>   (Hypervisor)

I create a brand new database, insert some rows, and then:

```
select * from table_1   
--> Query executed successfully, 50 rows

insert into table_2 select * from table_1   
--> Invalid object name 'table_2'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can we assume that table_2 exists and the name is properly qualified?

Comment: oh god I'm such such an idiot:  select * into table_2 from table_1

Comment: It happens to us all :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT INTO` works only when the table specified does not exist, so in your case if _table_2_ does not exist, then :

```
SELECT * INTO table_2 FROM table_1;
```

If `table_2` exist, then:

```
INSERT INTO table_2 SELECT (Col1, Col2, ..) FROM table_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot.

The correct syntax is:

```
select * into [table_2] from table_1
```

Comment: This is correct as long as `table_2` **does not yet exist**  only